# Looping Random Images with a Single Start/Stop Button (Two Different Click Events for the Same Button)

Tags: javascript, while-loop, addeventlistener

I'm a beginner in coding and JavaScript.
I'm trying to build a simple game as a learning experience, where a player will click a button to spin 10 images randomly and click the same button again to stop on one of the images. I'm trying to do this with a "while loop" and I'm trying to use two "addEventListener("click")" methods that are inside each other. With that, I'm trying to show fast/random images on the browser until the player clicks on the same button again. I can generate one random image per click, but I can't loop this behaviour until the second click. I think I crash my browser with my code. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
// Spinning images functionality
btnSpin.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let stop = 0;
  while (stop === 0) {
    // Genarate image number
    const imageNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 10);
    // Show image with the generated number
    animalEl.src = `animal-${imageNumber}.png`;

    btnSpin.addEventListener("click", function () {
      stop === 1;
      return stop;
    });
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `stop = 1;` is a fix.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: You are calculating the ids in the while loop as fast as possible and don't give your browser some time to display the images. Even if the browser could display your image changes you would see like thousands of images per second which i think is not what you want.

I recommend the method `setInterval(func, interval)`. This method will call a function in a specific interval and can be canceled anytime.

Here is an example how you could use this in combination with a single button to start and stop the interval:

```
let interval;

btnSpin.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    } else {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            // Genarate image number
            const imageNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 10);
            // Show image with the generated number
            animalEl.src = `animal-${imageNumber}.png`;
      }, 500);
    }
})
```

This will change the image every 500ms.

Here is also a JSFiddle which spins random background colors on first click and stops on second:
https://jsfiddle.net/721ajvhd/

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you very much! 

But I don't know how this loops without a loop, it's the first time I see setInterval method. I want to understand it if it's not too much trouble: I couldn't understand the function of the "interval" variable here; and I couldn't really figure out how the stopping click works here, since the click event is used only once. 

You can just direct me to a resource where I can understand this method too, if you don't have the time. Still, thanks much.

Comment: I think I understood how `setInterval` and `clearInterval` works. Though, still don't understand this part really:
  `if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;`

Comment: What I understand is we declare an undefined variable, and the if statement doesn't execute (cause it returns a falsy value I guess?) so it jumps to the else statement. setInterval executes and starts looping. But how does the loop stop? How does the value of interval change?

Comment: I think I got it. Once the interval is declared it becomes a true value and as soon as I click again, the if statement runs and it stops the interval. It works backwards almost. Very elegant. Thanks again and sorry for the million questions.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Yes you are right. The ```setInterval``` method returns a interval-id which we store in the ```interval``` variable. This is later used to 1. check if a interval is running (this is the case if the variable is assigned) and 2. to pass it to the ```clearInterval``` method so the interval can be found and stopped. Sidenote: ```if(variable)``` will evaluate to true if the variable is assigned thats why we need to set the ```interval```back to null when we stopped interval.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!